# 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found in RNFIRMessaging.h

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, cocoapods, google-mlkit

I want to archive ios part of a project written in react-native but in file `'RNFIRMessaging.h'` I get an error `'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h'` file not found.

I use `GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition` framework which requires that I use `use_frameworks!` in my Podfile. And together with `Firebase/Messaging` it forms a conflict.

I tried deleting `Podfile.lock` and reinstalling, using `modular_headers => true` and cleaning DerivedData directory but nothing seems to work.

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'

target 'app' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for handiCash
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.55.0'

  use_frameworks!
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition'

  pod 'yoga', path: "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"
  pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'Core',
    'RCTImage',
  ]

  pod 'Firebase', '6.9.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

 
  target 'appTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I use Xcode 12.5.1

Comment: Try moving the `use_frameworks!` directive to the top of the Podfile

Comment: Thanks @PaulBeusterien, I tried it but unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rolling back all my changes and started implementing them from scratch once again. This time for some reason it worked...